# test scripts work individually, but not when run through npm test?

Tags: node.js, npm, mocha.js

node version: 0.10.36
npm version 1.4.28

local istanbul version 0.3.2
local mocha version 1.21.4
local chai version 1.9.2

Inside my package.json I have these three scripts:

```
"pretest": "./node_modules/.bin/_mocha -R xunit > specs/spec-results.xml ./test/ --recursive --require chai",
"test": "./node_modules/.bin/istanbul cover ./node_modules/.bin/_mocha -- -R spec ./test/ --recursive --require chai",
"posttest": "./node_modules/.bin/istanbul report cobertura --root ./coverage/ --dir ./coverage/",
```

They all work individually when copied and pasted  into the command line, but when I run `npm test`, I don't see the same output. It appears to exit during the `pretest` script.

How can I fix this?

### EDIT 1:

My pretest command actually never works. Edited to
`./node_modules/.bin/_mocha --reporter-options output=specs/spec-results.xml ./test/ --recursive --require chai`, which does work.

When I run this command just by itself, I get the expected output where it shows the number of passing and failing tests.

When I run npm test, I get:

```
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

However, I also get the number of passing and failing tests, as I expect.

Comment: Does pretest exit with 0?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I don't see any indication that it does

Comment: We'll have you checked what it *does* exit with?

Comment: @jonrsharpe how do I do that?

Comment: If `pretest` exits with anything else than 0, npm will emit a very clear error message. I've just tried with `pretest` set to `exit 15`. Please edit the question to show the output you get when you run your commands outside npm and what you actually get when you run them with `npm test`.

Comment: @Louis my question is edited.

Comment: @jornsharpe, I edited my pretest command and _now_ it exits with code 0. when run through npm test.

Comment: @Houseman Everything seems to be working as it should. When any test fails, mocha returns a non-zero exit code, and `npm test` thus also fails. Or is it the case that you have no failing tests and you still get a failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my pretest command:

```
"./node_modules/.bin/_mocha -R xunit > specs/spec-results.xml ./test/ --recursive --require chai"
```

Apparently this is not the correct way to output the report to a file. The process would exit suddenly.

I changed it to this:

```
/node_modules/.bin/_mocha --reporter-options output=specs/spec-results.xml ./test/ --recursive --require chai
```

And it worked